# Spring Batch JobInstance to run more than once

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and trust me I have read a lot those day about it to try to be familiar with its concepts. I am a bit confused about how `JobInstance`, `RunIdIncrementer`, `JobParamaters` work and I would like to understand some aspects :

- When you run a Job and the `JobInstance` name is already in the `BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` table, the Job is not launched. So, what is the best way to generate a new name for my `JobInstance`?
- Is it a good practice to always generate a new name when I want to launch my job?
- As job is supposed to be scheduled to run many times. What is the best practice to create a Batch (Job) to be scheduled to run many times without generating a new name?
- Does the RunIdIncrementer() is supposed to create an **id** to generate a new JobName?

**Edit** : See the code below

```
@Bean
public Job batchExecution() {

    return jobs
            .get("BatchJob")
            .incrementer(new JobIdIncrementer())
            .start(downloadFile())
            .next(archiveFile())
            .next(readFile())
            .build();
}
```

The JobIdIncrementer :

```
public class JobIdIncrementer implements JobParametersIncrementer {

    private static String RUN_ID_KEY = "run.id";
    private String key;

    public JobIdIncrementer() {
        this.key = RUN_ID_KEY;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
        JobParameters params = parameters == null ? new JobParameters() : parameters;
        long id = new Date().getTime();
        return (new JobParametersBuilder(params)).addLong(this.key, Long.valueOf(id)).toJobParameters();
    }
}
```

When I start the Batch the fist time, I have this log (it works fine) :

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

"2018-08-08 15:36:03 - Starting Application on MA18-012.local with PID 39543 
""2018-08-08 15:36:05 - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
""2018-08-08 15:36:05 - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5SpatialDialect
""2018-08-08 15:36:06 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
""2018-08-08 15:36:09 - Started Application in 6.294 seconds (JVM running for 6.812)
""2018-08-08 15:36:09 - Loading the file name
""2018-08-08 15:36:23 - Downloading the file
""2018-08-08 15:36:24 - Archiving the file 
""2018-08-08 15:36:24 - Unzipping the file
""2018-08-08 15:36:24 - Removing the file
""2018-08-08 15:36:51 - Reading the file
""2018-08-08 15:36:52 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
""2018-08-08 15:36:54 - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
""2018-08-08 15:36:54 - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

The second time when start the Batch, I have this one (no error, but it starts and closes immediatly):

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

"2018-08-08 15:38:28 - Starting Application on MA18-012.local with PID 39638
""2018-08-08 15:38:28 - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
""2018-08-08 15:38:30 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
""2018-08-08 15:38:31 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5SpatialDialect
""2018-08-08 15:38:31 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
""2018-08-08 15:38:33 - Started Application in 6.376 seconds (JVM running for 6.873)
""2018-08-08 15:38:34 - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
""2018-08-08 15:38:34 - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: I normally added timestamp as param. Refer my blog https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/spring-batch-maven-hibernate-oracle-and-intellij/ at step10

Comment: I tried but is does not work. I am not able to execute the Job a second time. I even tried to override the RunIdIncrementer() by following this link : https://randyyaj.github.io/post/20151014_java/ but still have the same issue. For the moment I am generating a new Job Name. Not the good solution I guess.

Comment: Show us your code and logs

Comment: I suspect job name here is the name of job.  You should have misunderstood: It is always the same Job.  You are just submitting the same job with different parameter (hence creating a new corresponding JobInstance).  I make no sense to make a new name for the job every time

Comment: I know, but it is the only solution I found to run my job as many time I want. I admit that this not the solution and my question still is : How do I configure my job or write my job to not only run one time?

Comment: @HarryCoder As I said before: _submitting the same job with different parameter (hence creating a new corresponding JobInstance)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you run a Job and the JobInstance name is already in the BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE table, the Job is not launched. So, what is the best way to generate a new name for my JobInstance?

You don't need to change the job name each time. Your job can have multiple job instances, each one is identified by a key which is the hash of the (identifying) job parameters used to run your job.

> Is it a good practice to always generate a new name when I want to launch my job?

No, you don't need to generate a new name (it is the same job so the name should not change). What you need to do is to create a new job instance each time by specifying different job parameters.

> As job is supposed to be scheduled to run many times. What is the best practice to create a Batch (Job) to be scheduled to run many times without generating a new name?

Depending on the frequency of your job, you can add the date as a job parameter. For example, if your job is scheduled to run daily, the current date is a good parameter. Check this section of the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#job it provides an example.

> Does the RunIdIncrementer() is supposed to create an id to generate a new JobName?

The `RunIdIncrementer` increments the `run.id` job parameter so you get a new instance of `JobParameters` which will result in a new job instance. But the job name will still the same. Here is how it works: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/RunIdIncrementer.java#L44

Comment: Very useful. I still have the issue. I have updated my code above. Any idea?

Comment: The `JobParametersIncrementer` is used when you want to start the next instance of a job using the `CommandLineJobRunner` with the `-next` option or using the `JobOperator#startNextInstance`. I see you are using Spring Boot so I guess you are starting your job with `java -jar myjob.jar`. In this case, you need to specify different parameters to start a different job instance (for example `java -jar myjob.jar name=foo` and then `java -jar myjob.jar name=bar`) since the incrementer will no be used. You will see more details if your app with the `--debug` flag

Comment: Can you please provide a full sample command line `java -jar myjob.jar name=foo`?

Comment: Since you are using Spring Boot, your job will be packaged (by Spring Boot) in an executable jar that you can run with `java -jar myjob.jar`. Now if you want to pass parameters to your job, you can append them to the command like `java -jar myjob.jar param1=value1 param2=value2`